# How to show the scaled image and text in the view port without scrollbar?

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="img" src="img.png">
    <div clas="text">
        This is sample text.<br/>
        This is sample text.
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have the following css:

```
    .wrapper {
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

The image can be very big (4000px in width and 3000px in height). I cannot set the height of the div.wrapper. I cannot assume the amount of the text either. How can I use CSS to display the fully scaled-down image plus text in the viewport without the vertical scroll bar?

This is the example in jsfidille https://jsfiddle.net/c2q1w1tq/2/

Comment: Are you looking for a css-based only solution?

Comment: Which browser versions do you need to support?

Comment: Dekel, yes, I am looking for  a CSS only solution. Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: patrickhawley, Chrome, FF, IE, and Safari.  Recent versions only. Initially I thought this is an easy thing, but I am simply unable to make it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dekel sounds like you have a Javascript solution? Would you mind sharing it? Will the Javascript solution produce a responsive viewport? Thanks.

Comment: @curious1, Added a javascript-based solution. Please let me know if you checked it and if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are ok with a solution that also involve javascript you can use this:

```
function updateImageHeight() {
    textHeight = $('.wrapper').height() - $('.wrapper img.img').height()
    imgMaxHeight = $('.container').height() - textHeight
    $('.wrapper img.img').height(imgMaxHeight)
}
$(function() {
    updateImageHeight();
});
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    updateImageHeight();
})
```

> I used jquery here

The `$(window).on('resize'` will also give you a solution for window-resizing.

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ly8sac3v/

(I removed margin/padding for the html/body elements and wrapped everything in a container. In case you can't do that you can use the above code with the `body` element, however you might need some changes there).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am wondering how you can make the image responsive by modifying your code. I tried but not working. This is my code: $('.wrapper img.img').css('max-height', 'calc(100% - ' + textHeight + 'px)');

Comment: You can use `$('.wrapper img.img').css('max-height', imgMaxHeight)` instead of the `height` line in my example.

Comment: that works, but only for the height. When I make the window taller and samller, the height is indeed responsive. However, the width is not. I tried css: '.wrapper img.img {  max-width: 100%;}' Not working. Is this because we are using a Javascript solution?

Comment: Yes, basically you can't really combine the two (you can, but they will break the ratio).

Comment: Thanks for your follow up!